How to get process filename (untruncated) from ps output?
I would like a script to be able to check if a given process is running, and also get its process ID (PID), and so I was looking at ps process output.
If I execute with the cmd option for output, it seems I get the path to the executable and its command-line arguments:
[user@server ~]$  ps -o pid,cmd -A | grep gnome
1514 /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --autostart /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart

If I execute with the comm option for output, I will get a truncated process name:
[user@server ~]$  ps -o pid,comm -A | grep gnome
1514 gnome-session-b

So it's "gnome-session-b" instead of "gnome-session-binary".
I only want the PID and (non-truncated) process filename, so the cmd option seems like a better choice. However, if I look at nginx, it has some extra information in the output:
[user@server ~]$  ps -o pid,cmd -A | grep nginx
25147 nginx: master process nginx -c /opt/nginx/nginx.conf
25148 nginx: worker process

vs.
[user@server ~]$  ps -o pid,comm -A | grep nginx
25147 nginx
25148 nginx

In general with: -o <option(s)>, I'd like to get the requested information, and only that (not anything extra).
The goal is: process ID (PID) and (full, not truncated) process filename.
It seems the choice is cmd will get the full process name, but also give command-line arguments, and will also inform whether it's a "master process" or "worker process". I would like to get rid of that extra noise in the output.
Or the choice is comm, which will give the process name (only), but it has to be a short process name, or else it's truncated. nginx coincidentally is short enough, but other process filenames might be longer.
Are there any other options for ps output?
What is that extra information of "master process" or "worker process" referred to as? I didn't notice anything for it in the ps man page.

ps -o pid,exe might work - that gives you the actual path to the program, ignoring changes the program made to its own argv entries (which is what nginx appears to be doing).

Looks like: error: unknown user-defined format specifier "exe". ps --version has: procps-ng version 3.3.10

Probably Nginx rewrites its own argv[0] so there is no way really to get back the original value. Perhaps instead examine the /proc filesystem?

@tripleee note that viewing /proc/pid/exe link destination needs privileges

Wouldn't ps need the same privileges? Honestly reading /proc via C code, when there is already code that does work, would be so much better than this scripting using ps/grep nonsense. But the point of this question I guess is the script does use ps/grep, so how to fix it.

if you know the executable used by "a given process", you might be able to work backwards: eg. pidof /usr/sbin/nginx / pidof -x /my/bash/script

You are looking for ps -o pid,command

From the format specifiers section on the man page:

comm
command name (only the executable name).
[...]

Where as command refers to the args option that is defined as

args
command with all its arguments as a string.
[...]


comm truncates the name. I don't want it truncated. args doesn't truncate, but prints out "master process" and "worker process" for nginx. I don't know what that is, but I don't think it was part of the command-line arguments. Regardless, I don't want it there. I want process filename (not truncated) only.

@RichJahn try running ps with the -ww option

These 2 (with -ww):
ps -ww -o pid,comm -A | grep nginx and
ps -ww -o pid,cmd -A | grep nginx
have identical output as (withtout -ww):
ps -o pid,comm -A | grep nginx and
ps -o pid,cmd -A | grep nginx

@Rich Jahn, Re "I don't know what that is", Processes can edit their title/name on many OS (e.g. using prctl PR_SET_NAME on Linux). This allows them to show up as something different in ps output, which is useful for forking processes.
